# adding a jpanel to a jframe

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel

Is it possible to add a `JPanel` to a `JFrame`?  How can it be done?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

Comment: what did you try to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible - you can do it like this:

```
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

This panel will be the container in which you'll put all the components of your UI(except the menubar).

Answer (score 1):

yes, sure, same way as you would add any component to any container:

```
frame.add(panel)
```